# Android programming : copy folders from assets to /data/data/<packagename> folder

Tags: java, android, eclipse, copy, local

I want to write a project that on first run or installation it copies files and folders from Assets folder( app_webview,cache,databases,files,lib,shared_prefs ) which are folders inside Assets Folder to `/data/data/com.example.app/` I saw a code like this around here

i solved this by using this code. you can use this code to send any file from Assets/files/ to any where you want by replacing the getFilesDir().getParent() with the values i will provide below but i havent figure out how to send Folders

package com.paresh.copyfileassetstoAssets;

public class CopyFileAssetsToSDCardActivity1 extends Activity {
    /** Called when the activity is first created. */

```
Button button1;
Intent intent;
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main2);

    CopyAssets();
}


private void CopyAssets() {
    AssetManager assetManager = getAssets();
    String[] files = null;
    try {
        files = assetManager.list("Files");
    } catch (IOException e) {
        Log.e("tag", e.getMessage());
    }

    for(String filename : files) {
        System.out.println("File name => "+filename);
        InputStream in = null;
        OutputStream out = null;
        try {
          in = assetManager.open("Files/"+filename);   // if files resides inside the "Files" directory itself

          out = new FileOutputStream(getFilesDir().getParent().toString() + "/" + filename);

          copyFile(in, out);
          in.close();
          in = null;
          out.flush();
          out.close();
          out = null;
        } catch(Exception e) {
            Log.e("tag", e.getMessage());
        }       
    }
}
private void copyFile(InputStream in, OutputStream out) throws IOException {
    byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
    int read;
    while((read = in.read(buffer)) != -1){
      out.write(buffer, 0, read);
    }
```

button1 = (Button)findViewById(R.id.button1);

```
    button1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            intent = new Intent(CopyFileAssetsToSDCardActivity1.this, CopyFileAssetsToSDCardActivity2.class);
             startActivity(intent);

        }
    });
```

}

}

Comment: First some little things. `new File(toPath).mkdirs();`. Do not blindly call mkdirs(). First use .exists() to see if the directory exists. Check the return value of mkdirs(). If it is false you should r`eturn false;`

Comment: `new File(toPath).createNewFile();`. Remove that statement. It serves nothing.

Comment: `that it only copies specific file` ?? What do you mean? What kind of files(). copyAssetFolder() is a recursve function. Good. Please tell why it does not work.

Comment: `if (file.contains(".")) `. That is bad coding.

Comment: What is the biggest problem with both these codes?

Comment: For the rest: there are dozens of examples on stackoverflow how to do it. Why did you pick two who cannot differentiate between a file and a folder? As that is the problem here! You could have mentioned this problem.

Comment: You posted two solutions. But they are equal. So made no sense.

Comment: `copyAssetFolder(getAssets(), "files", 
                "/data/data/com.example.appname/files");`. Do not hardcode paths. `copyAssetFolder(getAssets(), "files", getFilesDir().getAbsolute.Path());`

Comment: I will not do that. I expect you to react on all my comments. If i take the time to comment then you can take the time to react.

Comment: The code is not that bad. In fact its nearly ok. The only thing that is wrong is `if (file.contains("."))`. I mentioned that already. So please start commenting on that. You only have to change this `if` and you are done.

Comment: I expect you to first tell what the problem with that if is. And what it really should do. Why is there an if in that code there? And why would that code have worked for the original author and does it not for you?

Comment: I am not interested in where you found your code. Please start answering to the point if you want help.

Comment: As soon as you know why that if is there. And as soon as you told exactly why the code does not work for you we continue. Even if you are not good at programming you should understand the principle of IF THEN ELSE.

Comment: `when i run it it didnot copy the file to the destination i wanted`. ??? Why so unclear? Which file? You got a lot of files in a lot of folders isnt it? Which destination? A different destinstion? Or was there no copy at all? You are giving vague info. Your info is not to the point. If the code does not do what you want then you should tell what it does instead.

Comment: Do we really have to believe that you do not understand this `if then else` statement; `if (file.contains("."))
                copyAsset(...)
            else copyAssetFolder(...};` Are you really not enable to explain whats happening here? Cannot believe it.

Comment: ok have solved half of my problem have updated the Question. did my home work well and achieved half of what i want but how can i make it copy folders and not only files. lets forget about the other post

Comment: Please remove all those system directories. Makes no sense. You posted completely new code that only copies files. Remove it and put back the code you posted first. Its unbelieveble that you removed all that code. I had told you that the code was pretty ok.

Comment: And if you have done that then explain what that if then else statement does.

Comment: Bro just show me how i can make the above code copy folders from Asset to /data/data/<packagename> the above code works for me so just help me on how i can get it to copy folders the other code is history

Comment: The 'history' code already copied folders and files. So put it back.

Comment: that file cannot be located any more by the way which of the code the first or the second code ?

Comment: The first will do.

Comment: thanks let me look for the code